# No missions available after finishing bail missions in GTA V

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

For some reason, I was doing bail missions but when I was done with them, I don't know what to do. I have no main story missions, or Strangers and Freaks missions for Trevor. I did the bail missions after Mr. Phillips on my PS3. What shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://gta.wikia.com/Mr._Philips), finishing Mr. Philips should unlock the two next missions: [Nervous Ron](http://gta.wikia.com/Nervous_Ron) and [Trevor Philips Industries](http://gta.wikia.com/Trevor_Philips_Industries), given respectively by Ron and Tao Cheng. So except if you're experiencing a bug blocking the following missions, you should already have access to these two.

If this is the exact point where you're stuck, maybe do you have a save file right before the first Trevor appearance? If you do, try to load it and replay the missions to see if something is triggered this time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have no save files before the first Trevor appearance on my PS3. :( Again, thanks for telling me.

Comment: I've read a thread on Rockstar website where a guy had apparently the same issue. But he mentioned Michael and Franklin were still playable after Mr. Philips, even though they shouldn't be. It is the same for you?

Comment: I did not have this problem. The only playable character I can play is Trevor.